# Let $J=\langle x,y\rangle$ and $I=J^3=J\cdot J\cdot J$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. (Two questions down below in the body...)

Tags: linear-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

Let $J=\langle x,y\rangle$ and $I=J^3=J\cdot J\cdot J$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

**1.1** The set of all monomials in $x, y$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. In particular, $x^2$ and $x^3$ are linearly independent in the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. Explain why $x^2 + I$ and $x^3 + I$ are linearly *dependent* in the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/I$.

**1.2** Find $\sqrt{I}$ and $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\sqrt{I})$ and $V(\sqrt{I})\subset \mathbb{Q^2}$ by hand.

Concerning **1.2**, I was thinking:

$I = J \cdot J \cdot J = J^3$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sqrt{I} = J$, since $J^3 = I$

$\sqrt{I} = \langle x,y\rangle$, $V(\sqrt{I}) = \lbrace(0,0)\rbrace$

$\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\sqrt{I} = \lbrace 1 \rbrace$

$\Rightarrow$ $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\sqrt{I}) = 1$

Does that make sense?

Concerning **1.1**, I don't really have a clue, so any help or explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: $x^3$ is in $I$.

Comment: @Eric has answered 1.1. As for 1.2, you're right up to and including $V(\sqrt I)$, but the next line is wrong. In particular, $\{1\}$ isn't even closed under addition, so it can't be the ring you want.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you. Is the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}$ then $2$ instead of $1$?

Comment: No, the quotient ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ and thus has dimension $1$.